# ionic scrollTop doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The html code is like this

`<div class="scrollTop" ng-show="showHide" ng-click="scrollTop($event)"></div>`

js code

```
$scope.pubScroll = function() {
    $scope.showHide = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top>50?true:false;
    console.log($scope.showHide)
}
```

The console is right,but element in page doesn't change,hide or show,where the
problem is ?

Comment: The function pubScroll was bind on `<ion-content></ion-content>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$scope.$apply();`to the function will resolve it.